# exposing rest services from the mean stack

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I am creating a web app using one of mean.io or mean.js for a mobile web site. From my mobile apps I want to be able to create users of this app using rest web services.  I want to access the mongodb with crud operations using restful api.  With mean.io or mean.js do you get these services for free? or how would you implement them?  I know express is part of this but I have not seen how exactly with mean stack you access these services.  Assuming basic add/remove user is provided with mean.io or mean.js I would still like to know how to add more rest accessible services like say inventory etc that is linked to the user.  Could someone point me in the right direction on this? Also is there difference between mean.io and mean.js in terms of rest services available by default and adding more rest services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother just use strongloop.io